# Can I remove an Office 2013 license key?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2013

I activated Office many times with KMS. So, a lot of activation information has been generated. I want use ospp to unpack it, but it cannot find the last five digits of the product key.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624350.aspx

I used `ospp /dstatusall`; that displays

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
SKU ID: 064383fa-1538-491c-859b-0ecab169a0ab
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusR_Retail edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, RETAIL channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
---------------------------------------
SKU ID: 090506fc-50f8-4c00-b8c7-91982a2a7c99
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeO365SmallBusPremR_SubTrial5 edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, TIMEBASED_SUB channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
---------------------------------------
SKU ID: 0bc1dae4-6158-4a1c-a893-807665b934b2
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeO365SmallBusPremR_Subscription2 edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, TIMEBASED_SUB channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
---------------------------------------
SKU ID: 0c4e5e7a-b436-4776-bb89-88e4b14687e2
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeO365ProPlusR_Retail edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, RETAIL channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
---------------------------------------
SKU ID: 149dbce7-a48e-44db-8364-a53386cd4580
LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeO365ProPlusR_Subscription1 edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, TIMEBASED_SUB channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
---------------------------------------
```

So, how do I clean these? I have uninstalled Office 2013, but they still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You Ask. . .

> **I want use ospp to unpack it, but it cannot find the last five digits of the product key.**

As specified in the **TechNet** [Tools to manage Office 2013 volume activation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624350.aspx) post. . .

> **`/unpkey:value`**
>
> > Uninstalls an installed product key with the last five digits of the product key to uninstall (as displayed by the `/dstatus` option). `Value` parameter is required.
>
> ---
>
> **`/dstatus`**
>
> > Displays license information for installed product keys.
>
> ---
>
> **`/dstatusall`**
>
> > Displays license information for all installed licenses.

So, since you say you've run `ospp /dstatusall` and gotten back a result of. . .

```
LICENSE STATUS:  ---UNLICENSED--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F014
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is not available.
```

*Then this would mean just what the error message is telling you, **there are no licensed products of those versions of Office on this machine** and it really should be as simple as that. So you don't need to worry about running the process with the `/unpkey:value` parameter.*

---

### You Ask. . .

> **So, how do I clean these? I have uninstalled Office 2013, but they still exist.**

You might give the [Completely uninstall Office with the easy fix tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) as shot but not sure how well it'd work since you've already uninstalled Office but it might be worth a shot at least.

> **Completely uninstall Office with the easy fix tool**
>
> 1. Click this easy fix button to uninstall Office.
>
>    <kbd>[**`Download`**](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall)</kbd>

Otherwise, I would suggest—***if you absolutely must***—hop on over to [Manually uninstall Office 2013 or Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-uninstall-Office-2013-or-Office-365-1d1110d5-75a4-4154-969e-4260ff29b232) and review all these details in more thoroughness.

However, to get you started, I'd say you'd likely want to focus on registry keys (and maybe some other miscellaneous items) so I'll reference the items of potential interest you may want to start with potentially but I'd personally not even worry about it and just leave as-is.

> **Step 4: Delete the Office service**
>
> Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator, type the following command, and then press Enter:
>
> `sc delete Clicktorunsvc`
>
> ---
>
> **IMPORTANT:** Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems may occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you start, [back up the registry for restoration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756) in case problems occur.
>
> **Step 6: Delete the Office registry subkeys**
>
> 1. Open **Registry Editor**.
>
>    - **Windows 10**: Right-click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedit**, and then click **OK**.
>    - **Windows 8** or 8.1: Right-click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedit**, and then click **OK**.
>    - **Windows 7**: Click **Start**, type **Run** in the **Start Search** box, and then click **Run** in the results.
> 2. Delete the following registry subkeys:
>
>    - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun`
>    - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppVISV`
>    - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Office`
>    - `<Edition>15 - en-us`
>    - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office`
>    - Then **Delete** the Office key.
>
> In the subkey in the third bullet item, "Microsoft Office 15 - en-us" represents the actual program name. This name depends on the Office 2013 edition and language version that you installed.
>
> **Step 8**: Uninstall the Microsoft Office Habanero local component and Habanero supplemental local component
>
> 1. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
> 2. At the command prompt, type the command that is appropriate for your operating system, and then press Enter:
>
>    - If you're running an x86 version of Office 2013 on an x64 operating system, run the following command:
>
>    **`MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-008F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}`**
>
>    - If you're running an x86 version of Office 2013 on an x86 operating system, run the following command:
>
>    **`MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-007E-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}`**
>
>    - If you're running an x64 version of Office 2013 on an x64 operating system, run the following command:
>
>    **`MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}`**
>
> ---
>
> **Step 5: Delete the registry subkeys for the Office system**
>
> - Before you start, [back up the registry for restoration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756) in case problems occur.
>
> > WARNING: Serious problems may occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These problems might require that you reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be solved. Modify the registry at your own risk.
>
> ---
>
> **Delete the Office 2013 registry subkeys**
>
> 1. Press Windows logo key + R to open the **Run** dialog box.
> 2. Type **regedit**, and then click **OK**.
> 3. Click the following registry subkey:
>
>    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0`
>
> 4.Click **File** > **Export**, type **DeletedKey01**, and then click **Save**.
>
> 5. Click **Edit** > **Delete**, and then click **Yes** to confirm.
> 6. Repeat steps 1 through 5 for each registry subkey in the following lists. Increment the name of the exported key by one for each subkey.
> 7. For example: Type **DeletedKey02** for the second key, type **DeletedKey03** for the third key, and so on.
>
> > NOTE:  In the following registry keys, the asterisk character (*) represents one or more characters in the subkey name.
>
> 32-bit versions of Windows
>
> - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Delivery\SourceEngine\Downloads\*0FF1CE}-*`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*0FF1CE*`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Upgrade Codes\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ose`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features\*F01FEC`\
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Win32Assemblies\*Office15*`
>
> 64-bit versions of Windows
>
> - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Delivery\SourceEngine\Downloads\*0FF1CE}-*`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*0FF1CE*`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ose`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\*F01FEC`
> - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Win32Asemblies\*Office15*`
>
> Also delete the following registry subkeys
>
> 1. Locate one of the following subkeys, depending on the version of Windows that you're running:
>
>    - 32-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
>    - 64 bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
> 2. Click **File** > **Export**, type **UninstallKey01**, and then click **Save**.
> 3. Under the **Uninstall** subkey that you located in step 1, click each subkey, and then determine whether the subkey has the following value assigned to it:
>
>    - Name: UninstallString
>    - Data: `file_name path\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe` path
>
>    In this example, file_name represents the actual name of an installation program, and path represents the actual file path.
> 4. If the subkey contains the name and the data that are described in step 3, click **Edit** > **Delete**. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until you locate and delete every subkey that matches the name and data that are described in step 3.
> 6. Close Registry Editor.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-uninstall-Office-2013-or-Office-365-1d1110d5-75a4-4154-969e-4260ff29b232)</sub>

Comment: I think " Delete the Office registry subkeys" is good idea, i try to search those informations in registry and find them.so i try to delete them. Wish my computer will be safe when I removed them.